# MassTransit: What's the best way to debug deserialization errors?

Tags: masstransit

For an unknown reason, MassTransit keeps moving messages of a specific type to the error queue. I believe that a [deserialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20519056/109941) is causing this.

What's the best way to debug deserialization errors?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out what's going on is enable one of the logging providers and look at the logs for a given consumer that's kicking stuff over. You might need to configure specific loggers, anything under MassTransit would be helpful.

In addition, I believe Chris added the some information to the envelop in a recent version of MT. You might be able to identify the error just by looking at the JSON or XML payload envelop in the message queue.